# Not able to run the runscript after restoring from a checkpoint in gem5 fs mode

Tags: gem5

I have been able to create a checkpoint on an ARM disk image running in the full system mode and restore from that checkpoint. But when I try to run runscript while restoring from that checkpoint using the "--script" flag (while running the script in configs/examples/fs.py), the script doesn't get executed. I have not been able to figure out why and any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Initially load the system(This works)-->`build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/bibin/projects/full-system-images/arm_18/disks/aarch64-ubuntu-trusty-headless.img --kernel=/home/bibin/projects/full-system-images/arm_18/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_emm64 --bootloader=/home/bibin/projects/full-system-images/arm_18/binaries/boot_emm.arm64 --cpu-clock=250MHz --caches`

Restoring from the checkpoint after creating the checkpoint through telnetting and /sbin/m5 checkpoint(this works as well) --> `build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/bibin/projects/full-system-images/arm_18/disks/aarch64-ubuntu-trusty-headless.img --kernel=/home/bibin/projects/full-system-images/arm_18/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_emm64 --bootloader=/home/bibin/projects/full-system-images/arm_18/binaries/boot_emm.arm64 --cpu-clock=250MHz --caches -r 1`

Trying the runscript while restoring from checkpoint(This doesn't work) --> `build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/bibin/projects/full-system-images/arm_18/disks/aarch64-ubuntu-trusty-headless.img --kernel=/home/bibin/projects/full-system-images/arm_18/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_emm64 --bootloader=/home/bibin/projects/full-system-images/arm_18/binaries/boot_emm.arm64 --cpu-clock=250MHz --caches --script=/home/bibin/projects/csr_parallelism/runscript_exit.rcS -r 1`

The contents of the runscript file is just this --> `/sbin/m5 exit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained here](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#m5-readfile), `--script` sets up the stdout produced by the `m5 readefile` op.

It does not actually just run that script automatically, you have to do that yourself.

To achieve this when taking a breakpoint manually, you can run [as explained here](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#gem5-restore-new-script):

```
sh -c 'm5 checkpoint;m5 readfile > /tmp/gem5.sh && sh /tmp/gem5.sh'
```

This way, when the checkpoint gets restored, we are in the middle for running a shell script that then does `m5 readfile` and executes its contents.